# How to load a custom directive specific CSS file in angularjs?

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a custom directive which has mutliple html elements with classes applied on them, and I have a CSS file specific to this directive, where all these classes were defined. 
What is the better way of loading this CSS file on demand, whenever I use the custom directive(in any of my views?

Comment: Is there any problem for you simply include it into the main html? What are the benefits for you in loading it on demand?

Comment: We have lazy loading concept implemented in our project. We don't load any files which are not used. and also this directive is part of a common module. Unless the view uses this directive, why pre loading it?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to dynamically generate link tags and add them to the document head. You'd probably want to wrap this behind a service that can keep track of which style sheets have already been loaded.

You'd also want to make sure you wait until the style sheet has been loaded and applied before showing your directive so that you don't get flashes of unstyled content.